# Using async task inside a WCF service operation hosted in a Windows Service

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous, windows-services

I have been told that you shouldn't do async things inside a WCF service hosted in IIS because after the service operation returns, IIS is free to cleanup any other associated threads, completed or not.

But what about a WCF service hosted in a windows service. Can I fire off async tasks there, inside the service operation, and return to the client with confidence the thread will be allowed to complete?

Having a hard time finding a straight answer to this.

Comment: 1) Well IIS does allow you to change the default **Idle Time-out** for an AppPool to _0_ meaning it will generally not times out.  This is a familiar pattern for WCF Workflow Applications with custom service factories.  2) Yes, you can have a Task-based WCF method or you can make the server invoke the client at a later date.  The client will need to expose an endpoint or utilise a two-way connection depending on just how long your task is going to take?  > 1 minute then server should hang up and call back later

Comment: I'm not really sure that is applicable to my situation at hand since my design is pretty set on a local service over net.pipes. But I do appreciate response since the info may be helpful in the future.

Comment: My second point addresses your second question regardless of whether you are using `net.pipe` or not